# RETURNING must contain at least one value

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm, pq

I'm learning to use PostgreSQL and GORM. Trouble came relatively quickly, and it feels as if I'm the only one having this problem ever.

Here, I'm creating a struct, instantiating it, and trying to write it to database. However, it returns an error:

```
pq: RETURNING must contain at least one value
```

Tried googling it, and the only thing I found is Postgres source code which might as well be in Chinese.

Source code:

```
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "user=postgres dbname=testdb sslmode=disable password=qwerty")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer db.Close()

database := db.DB()

err = database.Ping()
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

db.AutoMigrate(&Currency{})

fmt.Println("Connection to PostgreSQL was successful!")

testCur := Currency{"shekels", 20}
if db.NewRecord(testCur) {
    err := db.Create(&testCur).Error
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Struct:

```
type Currency struct {
name string
rate uint
}
```

And yes, it *must* be done with Postgres and GORM. Database is brand new, empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that stands out is that your `struct` only contains non-exported fields:

```
type Currency struct {
    name string
    rate uint
}
```

Neither of those fields will be visible to Gorm (which presumably uses reflection to convert your `struct` to SQL). That would lead to Gorm trying to do an empty `INSERT` with a [`RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html) clause to get something back but, since Gorm can't see anything to INSERT it won't be asking for anything in the RETURNING clause and there's your rather confusing error.

I think you'll have better luck if you fix your `struct` to export those fields:

```
type Currency struct {
    Name string
    Rate uint
}
```

Comment: Indeed I have. Working as intended now. Looks like I still have to get used to Go syntax. Thanks a lot!